# Для чего использовать кеш второго уровня

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Вопрос теоретический, изучаю ОРМ, Понимаю , что  есть кеш первого уровня,  он  привязан к объекту сессии. А есть кеш второго уровня, и он привязан к фабрике сессий, вопрос, а когда и для чего его этот кеш второго уровня нужно использовать. Понимаю что его нужно настраивать.

Comment: просто загуглил [кэш второго уровня hibernate](https://habr.com/ru/post/135176/)

Comment: @tym32167  Спасибо за ответ, это я читал, но мне хочется более глубокого понимания. И из опыта опытных людей и простыми словами.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под `более глубоким пониманием`? У вас есть какой то конкретный вопрос? Там просто в статье и так все разжевано уже.